# SQL - How to get a duplicate column based on the value of another column

Tags: sql, join, request, exists

I have a query that return values ​​based on a boolean column: if the id_crsp includes a boolean true AND false, then it is selected.
Values ​​of id_crsp that have only a true or false value are not selected.

From this result, I would like to sort the id_crsp which have duplicates, and select only the one with the oldest date

Database values :

| id | idcrsp | date | boolean |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 11-2022 | true |
| 2 | 100 | 07-2022 | false |
| 3 | 200 | 06-2022 | false |
| 4 | 300 | 09-2022 | true |
| 5 | 300 | 08-2022 | false |
| 6 | 400 | 10-2022 | false |
| 7 | 100 | 01-2022 | false |
| 8 | 100 | 02-2022 | false |

My actual request :

```
SELECT true_table.* FROM mydb as true_table 
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT * FROM mydb WHERE requalif=TRUE) as false_table 
ON true_table.idcrsp = false_table.idcrsp 
AND true_table.requalif = FALSE;
```

This return :

| id | idcrsp | date | boolean |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8 | 100 | 02-2022 | false |
| 7 | 100 | 01-2022 | false |
| 2 | 100 | 07-2022 | false |
| 5 | 300 | 08-2022 | false |

I would like to enrich my request in order to have only two lines:

- id 5
- id 7 (which has duplicates of id_crsp and which has the oldest date).

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using your original query could you just add row_number and partition it by the idcrsp and then order by date descending. then just pick the rows where rn = 1

```
select * from
(SELECT true_table.*, row_number() over (partition by id_crsp order by date desc) rn  FROM mydb as true_table 
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT * FROM mydb WHERE requalif=TRUE) as false_table 
ON true_table.idcrsp = false_table.idcrsp 
AND true_table.requalif = FALSE)
where rn = 1
```

Comment: Thank's, just changed desc by asc, it works perfectly !

Answer (score 0):

How to get, from this last reponse/request :

```
select * from
(SELECT true_table.*, row_number() over (partition by id_crsp order by date desc) rn  FROM mydb as true_table 
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT * FROM mydb WHERE requalif=TRUE) as false_table 
ON true_table.idcrsp = false_table.idcrsp 
AND true_table.requalif = FALSE)
where rn = 1
```

the idcrsp, the date for the min false boolean value, **AND the date for the true boolean value wich the most recent date ??**

Thank's